# Is it possible to reset the contents of my OneDrive cloud storage to default?

Tags: windows-10, sync, onedrive, reset

I'm planning on upgrading to a new computer either this year or next year, market permitting. I currently use a Microsoft account to log into my Windows machine, as well as the OneDrive integration to more easily synchronize 1PassWord and other application settings between my computer and my laptop.

Now, the problem I have is that because I've been using OneDrive on Windows 10 since Windows 10 was originally introduced in 2015, on my previous computer, my OneDrive is cluttered with thousands of files, ranging from ancient documents I no longer need to game saves from games I haven't played in years, and even a bunch of duplicate files that weren't synced properly because of concurrent access on multiple machines.

I'd like to just make Tabula Rasa: copy out the things I desperately need and then reset my OneDrive to pristine conditions, so I can start fresh. The problem is that I'm not sure if it's possible to just delete every file in my OneDrive directory and call it a day, because OneDrive by default also contains a bunch of user folders, like documents, pictures, videos,...

I've tried searching for "reset OneDrive", but that only is for when the syncing program itself fails and needs to be reset, it doesn't delete any data. I can't seem to find any clean solution for resetting the contents of your OneDrive folder to a clean slate, beyond doing it manually, which as I've said above I'm worried might damage my Windows install.

Is there a proper way to reset the contents of my OneDrive folder to a clean slate?

---

To clarify: I know I can do a manual cleanup of my OneDrive, but I don't know what files and folders in my current mangled install are files I created myself and which ones are a core part of Windows 10 that I should not delete. I was hoping to not have to figure this out myself by finding a way to reset my OneDrive state to a known good default as defined by Microsoft.

Comment: You may want to reach out to OneDrive tech support

Comment: You can delete an entire folder in one go. Doesn't that help in your case, to delete only some of the folders? ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/delete-files-or-folders-in-onedrive-21fe345a-e488-4fa7-932b-f053c1bebe8a))

Comment: You can simply delete the files you no longer need.  Files deleted from your OneDrive folder will synchronized to all machines.  This does mean you will permanently delete the file.

Comment: You may refer to "[Delete files or folders in OneDrive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/delete-files-or-folders-in-onedrive-21fe345a-e488-4fa7-932b-f053c1bebe8a)". You could delete content manually on OneDrive online or File Explorer.

Comment: @Nzall There are no files within OneDrive that are a "_...are a core part of Windows 10_". The default state of OneDrive contains no files [those are added by the user]; it does contain helper category folders, but those are just that - helper directories for categorization.